# Can I use a TVS diode to remove spikes in SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, tvs, snubber

I have an almost working Half-Bridge SMPS that has some ringing in the output like this (not the real output, just and image I found):

[image]

I have eliminated almost all the oscillation using a snubber network on the secondary side (C=2.2nF and R=15 Ohm). The problem is that this spikes are still there and this is translated to the rectified output. If I increase the value of the capacitor in the snubber this spikes gets lower but the dissipated power in the resistor increases a lot (a 3W resistor just burns instantly with a 10nF capacitor).

The square wave has a max value of about 50V and this spikes are about 90V. I though in adding a TVS diode in series to the capacitor and the resistor in the snubber network with a breakdown voltage of around 50V to remove this spikes. Is this feasible? Or would it be better to just add a bigger capacitor value with a bigger resistor?

**EDIT:**

This is the output stage:

[image]

D6 is a MUR3060, R15 is 3W metalfin, C17 and C18 are low ESR capacitors.

**edit:** I'm probing with this:
[image: oscilloscope probe with a spring clip]

**edit:** My circuit is a half-bridge SMPS like this:
[image]

Comment: TVS diodes by design is to work as mutch as close to source and directly to the ground, without any other component in between.

Comment: Show your circuit (at least the output stage).

Comment: @Andyaka see my edited question

Comment: How are you probing the spikes?  Is it a passive probe? Are you using good, low inductance probing techniques?

Comment: @MD Yes, I'm with this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8dDrt.jpg

Comment: Did you say it was a half bridge circuit? I was expecting a centre tap on the primary?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, It's a Half-Bridge SMPS like this: http://goo.gl/Z8dibI

Comment: In my opinion , spikes is due to the secondary leakage inductance , try smaller value of snubber resistor , keep capacitor value small...

Comment: Can you expand on why you believe so?

Comment: Did you try to slow down the switching rise times? Is it a option?